# Access unknown javascript object property by variable

Tags: javascript, jquery, object, properties

I have a javascript object literal operating as a "class".  It has a "settings" object.  In that settings object, there's a key called "username" which is also an object that contains two properties:  "field" and "label".

Now, I'm trying to dynamically populate a table based on jQuery.get().  While iterating through the resulting data object (rows), I'm trying to access the username property... but it can be another field other than "username".  It could be "name", etc.  The name of the field is stored in the "this.settings.username.field" key.  How do I access this?

```
var r = new Array(), j = -1;
        for (var key=0, size=response.length; key<size; key++){
            r[++j] ='<tr><td><input type="checkbox" /></td>';
            if(this.settings.username_mode != 'name' && this.settings.username_mode != 'email'){
                r[++j] ='<td>';
                r[++j] = data[key].[this.settings.username.field];
            }
            r[++j] = data[key][];
            r[++j] = '</td><td class="whatever1">';
            r[++j] = data[key][1];
            r[++j] = '</td><td class="whatever2">';
            r[++j] = data[key][2];
            r[++j] = '</td></tr>';
        }
```

The equivalent in PHP would be:

```
$r[++j] = $data[$key]->{$this->settings->username->field}
```

Comment: Remove the period -> `data[key][this.settings.username.field];`

Comment: That was it, thanks!